# Placing Changing Directory Name into Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, directory, copy

Here's my situation. I need to move all the files from a certain directory (which happens to change each day) into a static unchanging directory. How can I create a script which will grab that new directories name, place it into a variable, and then use that directory variable to move the files to the static directory?

thanks

Comment: What language or platform are you using?

Comment: We can't read your mind. Forget for a moment that you want a script to find the "new" folder. Tell us how would you identify the "new" folder. By creation date? by name? by location? We need to know the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
move "%~1\*.*" "\Static\Dir" /Y
```

Place the name of the changing directory as parameter of the Batch file; enclose it in quotes if the name may contain spaces:

```
test.bat "The dir of today"
```